# How do I verify a device advertised as Bluetooth 5.0 is indeed 5.0 and not fake

Tags: audio, bluetooth, dongle

I have a Bluetooth 5.0 dongle purchased from Amazon at the link below:

https://www.amazon.co.uk/Maxesla-Bluetooth-Wireless-Transmitter-Controller/dp/B0851FBP3X

Performance-wise it does not seem to live up to the increased range and multiple audio device connection claims of Bluetooth 5.0 and I wonder whether it's a fake 5.0 device. Is there any Windows software that allows you to query a Bluetooth device's capabilities and Bluetooth version? Does the extended range and multiple connections only work when Bluetooth 5.0 devices are connecting with a Bluetooth 5.0 dongle. I'm wondering if my issues are due to my connecting Bluetooth 4.x devices to the Bluetooth 5.0 dongle?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Find Bluetooth version in Windows 10**

You can easily check the Bluetooth version of your Windows 10 PC via the device manager.

Press Win+X to open the Start Menu and select Device Manager.

Under Bluetooth, you will see several Bluetooth devices.

[image]

Select your Bluetooth brand and right click to check the Properties

[image]

Go to the Advanced tab and check the firmware version. The LMP number shows the version of Bluetooth your PC is using.

Below is the LMP version table-

```
LMP 11.x - Bluetooth 5.2
LMP 10.x - Bluetooth 5.1
LMP 9.x  – Bluetooth 5.0
LMP 8.x  – Bluetooth 4.2
LMP 7.x  – Bluetooth 4.1
LMP 6.x  – Bluetooth 4.0
LMP 5.x  – Bluetooth 3.0 + HS  (deprecated, to be withdrawn)
LMP 4.x  – Bluetooth 2.1 + EDR (deprecated, to be withdrawn)
LMP 3.x  – Bluetooth 2.0 + EDR (withdrawn)
LMP 2.x  – Bluetooth 1.2  (withdrawn)
LMP 1.x  – Bluetooth 1.1  (withdrawn)
LMP 0.x  – Bluetooth 1.0b (withdrawn)
```

Or you can use Bluetooth Version Finder

It is a very simple tool which comes in a zipped file. All you need to do is to download and run the tool and it will instantly give you the Bluetooth version and the name of the Bluetooth device running on your PC. It is a portable freeware and you can use it any of your PCs.

[Bluetooth Version finder](https://www.sordum.org/10772/bluetooth-version-finder-v1-1/) (Link to website)

[image]

Hope it helps!

*[Source](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/what-bluetooth-version-is-on-my-pc-f5d4cff7-c00d-337b-a642-d2d23b082793) for the LMP table*

Comment: FYI. With the information of the above answer and the software linked, I was able to determine that my device in question showed an LMP number 10.11707, which is apparently Bluetooth 5.1.

Comment: what to do if the device properties miss Advanced tab? how to detect firmware?

Comment: Any idea/tool on how to check on mac?

Comment: Yeah this might be a new question but im not sure if this has been answered on Ask Different, Anyway this might help you: [link](https://www.mathworks.com/help/supportpkg/parrot/ug/check-the-bluetooth-version-of-your-mac-system.html)